# Combine Sass mixin and CSS class?

Tags: css, sass

I've created a Sass mixin and a CSS class which have the same styling, so developers have the option to either add the class to the HTML or apply the mixin with Sass.

```
@mixin link-style-1 {
    background: $red;
    padding:  .75em 45px .75em 5%;
}
.link-style-1 {
    background: $red;
    padding:  .75em 45px .75em 5%;
}
```

Is there a way of combing these 2 into 1? know I could use a variable for the padding for both, but then my code will get a bit longer and harder to read. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just include the mixin in the class for DRYness:

```
@mixin link-style-1 {
    background: $red;
    padding:  .75em 45px .75em 5%;
}
.link-style-1 {
    @include link-style-1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no real reason for that to be a mixin. You could use a placeholder selector and extend that for the class.

```
%link-style-1 {
    background: $red;
    padding:  .75em 45px .75em 5%;
}
.link-style-1 {
    @extend %link-style-1;
}
```

When you do this, the placeholder ("silent class") is not output to CSS, much like a mixin; however, every selector that extends it will be combined, instead of causing code duplication like that from a mixin.